# How to import csv data into specific columns of mysql while set other columns by myself

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I had a table looks like this:

```
result
================
item_id, condition_id, time, value
```

I need import a csv file with the size of 500*2 into "time" and "value", and I want to set the "item_id" and "condition_id" as 1 and 2 for these data, respectively. What should I do?

Comment: Read up on load data infile and edit your question with what you try  if you run into difficulty,https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question in two substeps as follows. How can I do the same thing in one step?

**Step 1**

```
load data infile "file_path\\data.dat" into table test
fields terminated by '\t'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
(time, value);
```

**Step 2**

```
update test set item_id=1, condition_id=2
where item_id is null
```